# Python Opencv DLL load failed - Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, opencv, windows-10

This is an error that I've seen in several different places but none of the listed solutions have worked for me.

I'm trying to use opencv but when I import the module I get the following error:

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have tried installing opencv from a pre-downloaded package, my computer has the current windows media pack and I jave run the module the depends without it listing any dependecy errors, I'm not sure what else to try at this point.

Edit: I have also tried installing opencv-contrib-python to no avail.

Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated from python 3.7.3 to python 3.7.6 and it fixed the problem. Worth a shot if you have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue and I solved it using:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```